# CSS set li indent

Tags: html, css

Googling and searching stack overflow did not return any results that I could recognize, so forgive me if this has been asked before...

I have drop down main menu which uses lists as its basis. The problem is, the lists are very wide, and they do not indent far enough when expanded. So, this is my problem! How do I make the indent amount on lists larger via CSS?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

to indent a `ul` dropdown menu, use

```
/* Main Level */
ul{
  margin-left:10px;
}

/* Second Level */
ul ul{
  margin-left:15px;
}

/* Third Level */
ul ul ul{
  margin-left:20px;
}

/* and so on... */
```

You can indent the `li`s and (if applicable) the `a`s (or whatever content elements you have) as well , each with differing effects.
You could also use `padding-left` instead of `margin-left`, again depending on the effect you want.

**Update**

By default, many browsers use `padding-left` to set the initial indentation. If you want to get rid of that, set `padding-left: 0px;`

Still, both `margin-left` and `padding-left` settings impact the indentation of lists in different ways. **Specifically:** `margin-left` impacts the indentation on the outside of the element's border, whereas `padding-left` affects the spacing on the inside of the element's border. [(Learn more about the CSS box model here)](https://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/)

Setting `padding-left: 0;` leaves the li's bullet icons hanging over the edge of the element's border (at least in Chrome), which may or may not be what you want.

Examples of padding-left vs margin-left and how they can work together on ul: https://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/bb7kj8cr/1/

Comment: margin and padding are both correct to the question, it's a matter of design needs from there.

Comment: `padding-left` is the correct setting, at least in Chrome 54.0 and Firefox 49.0; both appear to be set to 40px as defaults for `ul` elements.

Answer (score 100):

`padding-left` is what controls the indentation of `ul` not `margin-left`.

Compare: Here's setting `padding-left` to `0`, notice all the indentation disappears.

```css
ul {
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>section a
    <ul>
      <li>one</li>
      <li>two</li>
      <li>three</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>section b
    <ul>
      <li>one</li>
      <li>two</li>
      <li>three</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

and here's setting `margin-left` to `0px`. Notice the indentation **does NOT change**.

```css
ul {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>section a
    <ul>
      <li>one</li>
      <li>two</li>
      <li>three</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>section b
    <ul>
      <li>one</li>
      <li>two</li>
      <li>three</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct (perhaps it has changed). My default stylesheet appears to use the `padding-inline-start` property, which takes into account directionality of the text: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-inline-start

Answer (score 51):

Also try:

```
ul {
  list-style-position: inside;
}
```

Comment: The actual answer!

Comment: yes does the job of aligning bullets to text in latest Chrome

Answer (score 7):

```
li{
    margin-left:50px;
}
```

or replace 50px with whatever you want.

Comment: You can also use a negative number here if you want to reduce the amount of indent.

Answer (score 2):

Using the chrome dev tools and looking at the styles applied to a `ul` element by the `user agent stylesheet` (at the time of writing), the default styles in Chrome are:

```
ul {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: disc;
    margin-block-start: 1em;
    margin-block-end: 1em;
    margin-inline-start: 0px;
    margin-inline-end: 0px;
    padding-inline-start: 40px;
}
```

The [`padding-inline-start`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-inline-start) property is used to set the indentation of the bullets (and the bullets of child lists).

> The padding-inline-start CSS property defines the logical inline start padding of an element, which maps to a physical padding depending on the element's writing mode, directionality, and text orientation.

(The other default properties may also help people get the look that they're after)

Note that this was mentioned earlier in a comment by @preferred_anon on [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28597518/4289902), but I missed that when I was first looking, so I've added this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found that doing it in two relatively simple steps seemed to work quite well.  The first css definition for ul sets the base indent that you want for the list as a whole.  The second definition sets the indent value for each nested list item within it. In my case they are the same, but you can obviously pick whatever you want.

```
ul {
    margin-left: 1.5em;
}

ul > ul {
    margin-left: 1.5em;
}
```