# Numbering of sub-llists with GitHub-markdown

Tags: markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I want to create a list like that.

```
 - one
 - two
  1. sub-one
  2. sub-two
     1. sub-sub-one
     2. sub-sub-two
```

But markdown (on GitHub) use *i, ii, ...* and for the sub-list and *a, b, c, ...* for the sub-sub-list.

How can I modify this behaviour with that markdown-code.

```
  # one
  # two
    1) sub-one
    2) sub-two   
     1) sub-sub-one
     2) sub-sub-two
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you make lettered lists using markdown?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13366820/how-do-you-make-lettered-lists-using-markdown)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Markdown itself can not do that.

But some workarounds can be found in the duplicate question [How do you make lettered lists using markdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13366820/4865723).